# Creating a msg on close when sheets are unprotected in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm trying to make it so that excel will look if two specific sheets are protected on closure and then if they are not I want a message box to come up warning of this. Currently i've got this far with VBA.

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

If Sheets("Dashboard Page").ProtectContents = True And Sheets("Tracker Sheet").ProtectContents = True Then

  MsgBox "Protected"
ElseIf 
MsgBox("Workbook is not protected please protect before closing", _
        vbQuestion + vbOKOnly) = vbOKOnly Then
    Cancel = True
End If



 End If
End Sub
```

if anyone could help out that would be great.
Thanks

Edit: I'm now having issues with changing this to just an OK button that cancels the close. changes are above. It will just close if the OK button is clicked

Comment: you cannot define a sub inside some `IF` of another sub. Retry by making all this as one `Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)`.

Comment: This fixed it. I tried this before but I had used a different sub name. Is Sub Workbook a specific sub for when you want to do something with the close command?

Comment: When placed inside the `ThisWorkbook` code module, `Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)` is an event handler for the close command.

Comment: ah ok that make sense. i'm having some issue now with changing the code from vbYesNo to vbOKOnly. i will make an edit to my post to explain

Comment: VBA doesn't give (AKAIK) any way to rename the standard event handlers for the worksheet modules. In any event -- from a design point of view I don't see why you need to pop up `Protected` when it is in fact protected. Why annoy a user (even if for only a second) if they haven't made any mistakes that need correcting?

Comment: sorry that was just for me to see that the if statement was working.

Comment: FWIW it's not fixed. You have one `Sub` declaration and two `End Sub`, one of which is inside an `If` block. And your indentation is making the code dangerously hard to follow. Your code can't possibly compile as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you can not open a sub inside another one, but you can call it.

```
Sub ProtectMsg_BeforeClose()

If Sheets("Dashboard Page").ProtectContents = True And Sheets("Tracker Sheet").ProtectContents = True Then
    MsgBox "Protected"
Else
    Workbook_BeforeClose
End If
End Sub

Sub Workbook_BeforeClose()
If MsgBox("Workbook is not protected please protect before closing", _
        vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
    Cancel = True
End If

End Sub
```

Try if it helps you.